# SQL Server 2005 query uses ? which doesn't work in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I'm working on an application which queries live data on SQL Server. The user enters a name within '% %' marks to search. Ie. if the user was to search for the owner of a property such as Noble, they would enter %noble%.

We recently upgraded both the application and the SQL Server that stores the data from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012.

The existing query and the new query are **identical:**

```
SELECT aurtvalm.pcl_num 
FROM aurtvalm 
INNER JOIN rtpostal ON aurtvalm.ass_num = rtpostal.ass_num
WHERE rtpostal.fmt_nm2 LIKE ?
```

In the old version, the above query produces 16 results. The exact same query in 2012 version produces an error:

> Incorrect Syntax near '?'

Has the use of the `?` symbol changed since SQL Server 2005?

Comment: Apologies - first time I have posted.

Comment: accepted and deleted my comment

Comment: Are you sure with question mark? May be the statement is copied from some code? I don't remember such a syntax...

Comment: Yes it's definitely a question mark. The application previously used spatialware in SQL 2005, perhaps this added additional syntax?
Question has been resolved, another component of the application declares the variable I needed. Turns out the old 2005 version does not do this.

Comment: Even SQL Server 2005 always used **named parameters** - not `?` for its parameters - something like `@searchterm` or something like that. `?` was used with the `OleDbProvider`, mostly for accessing MS Access and other OleDB databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That because you have incorrect syntax. You have to use parameter instead of question mark. Something like:

```
SELECT aurtvalm.pcl_num 

FROM aurtvalm 
INNER JOIN rtpostal ON aurtvalm.ass_num = rtpostal.ass_num

WHERE rtpostal.fmt_nm2 like @param
```

Comment: When did this component change? The old version works but the new doesn't so I'm assuming it must have changed at some point since. Also, would this require me to declare the @param variable?

Comment: Thanks for your help Stanislovas, You definitely put me on the right track to resolve this.